# Fix Androud glide issue, GlideApp errors in android studio

Tags: android-glide

I have a java class in my app PostViewHolder and I am trying to load an image using Glide but I get error, I am not the original developer of the code, it appears it was developed 3 years ago and so i don't know how best to explain.

I have this code line in my PostViewHolder

```
Imageutil.loadImageCenterCrop(GlideApp.with(baseActivity), imageUrl, postImageView, width, height);
```

For this line, **GlideApp.with(baseActivity)** is underlined red with error saying **Required type: GlideRequests, provided:.........**

I tried to change it to **Glide.with** and it shows cannot resolve symbol 'Glide'

On my project Glide is extending a class to load image with GlideApp

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
   @Override
 public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry)
   { registry.prepend(String.class  ByteBuffer.class, new Base64ModelLoadeeFactory();}
}
```

I will appreciate any help to get rid of the error **Required type:GlideRequests**

How to make this code work **Imageutil.loadImageCenterCrop(GlideApp.with(baseActivity), imageUrl, postImageView, width, height);**

Answer (score 0):

Short and simple way would be `Glide.with(context).load(imgUrl).into(imgView)`

Comment: add latest version dependancy of glide